# disown a process in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

The "disown" command works in bash, but not in ksh.

If I have started a process in ksh, how can I "disown" it, so I can exit my shell. 
(I know about nohup, but the process has already started!)

Answer (score 3):

ksh93 supports the disown command. Also, some versions of nohup allow you to specify a process id with the -p option, instead of a command.

Answer (score 0):

In ksh just run disown without -h option. That's it.

From the `ksh(1)` manual:

> ```
> disown [ job... ]
>     Causes the shell not to send a HUP signal to each given job, or all active
>     jobs if job is omitted, when a login shell terminates.
> ```